# Yaml Extension for PHP

Tags: php, linux, apache2

I have installed the YAML library for php via pecl.  I added the extension to the php.ini file.  And i can see that it is loaded, and enabled via phpinfo().

```
yaml

LibYAML Support enabled
Module Version  1.1.0-dev
LibYAML Version 0.1.3
```

However, when i use yaml_parse() in my php code, it comes with a fatal error of function not found.

Does any one have any ideas, as to what may be happening?

Thank You,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the extension installed in CLI and not in webserver config or vice versa?